# Aplicação wpf com entity framework não funciona em outra maquina

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, entity-framework, wpf

Tenho uma aplicação wpf com entity framework e sql server express...funciona perfeitamente no meu pc,mas quando tento instalar em outro computador não funciona...a aplicação nao cria o banco de dados com o code frst do entity createIfNotExists() e o app não abre, nao executa.O estranho é que no meu pc quando executo o app ele cria o banco certinho e roda a aplicação.

minha string de conexão:

```
    <add name="BarberSystem.Properties.Settings.BancoTesteConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BARBER_DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="BARBER_DATABASE" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=BARBER_DATABASE;integrated security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

o construtor da minha classe contexto do entity

```
 public BancoDados()
        : base("name=BARBER_DATABASE") {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BancoDados>());
    }
```

Comment: Gere um log da sua aplicação pra poder ver a exceção que ocorre. Em primeira instância eu verificaria se a connectionstring está correta na nova máquina, mas é melhor visualizar o log de exceções pra ter informações sobre o que está acontecendo internamente na aplicação.

Comment: Eu tenho uma classe de log...a mensagem que recebi no meu log foi:CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database master

Comment: Então o problema é a permissão do usuário que a aplicação está utilizando. Você precisa conceder a permissão de dbcreator para o usuário que sua aplicação utiliza (ou no grupo de usuários). Você pode fazer isso através do próprio management studio.